# Google Cloud Storage PHP - Weird response

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I tried to read/download a test file called "test.jpg" from my bucket on Google Cloud Storage via the Google Cloud PHP API.

I tried to read the file via:

```
try 
        {
           $object = $storageService->objects->get( $bucket, $file_name );
           $request = new Google_Http_Request($object['mediaLink'], 'GET');
           $signed_request = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
           $http_request = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($signed_request);
           echo $http_request->getResponseBody();
        }      
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
```

The API Call works fine (as I can see in the Google Cloud API Console), but as a response I only get a full page with something like that:

[image]

What am I making wrong?

Comment: When you open a .jpg file in a text editor (eg. Notepad++), it's what you see. You should try readfile http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: @Carlos2W yes, but in this case `$object['mediaLink']` should normally return the link to the file, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Paul: you're not wrong, but your code takes said link, follows it, and then echoes the results.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough thx for the quick reply. Is there a way to let users directly download the files from the GCS without having to set the file permission to public?

Comment: Yes, totally. The feature is called "signed URLs". Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough thx again for the quick reply. I thought with my script I already use signed urls? I'm kind of confused now. I just want my users to be able to get time limited access to directly download a file from my GCS.

Comment: I don't believe so. "sign()" was the function that I believe meant "attach authentication headers". For the current version of the PHP client, the equivalent code is "$httpClient = $client->authorize($httpClient);" See: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_abstract-classes-have-been-removed

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough thx for your help. I figured out how to create a signed url to get file access. I just have one last question. Do you know where I can see how many calls there have been? With the script I posted here as question I always saw every API call in the API Manager but with signed urls I don't see them in the API Manager when I open the signed url.